# Power BI Visual broken due to missing relationship

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to wrap my head around this conundrum and I'm drawing blanks.

I have Table Locals  which is a list of locations each person is located in and during what dates:

```
Name     Location    Date Start     Date End
Paul     Las Vegas   2019/01/01     2020/12/31
Tom      Los Angeles 2019/03/21     2020/02/14
Susan    New York    2019/08/30     2020/06/28
Paul     Chicago     2021/01/01     2021/12/31
```

and Table Contracts which is a table of contracts (each person can have more than one contract):

```
ID (unique)   Person ID        Type       Date
1             345456345        Video      2019/02/05
2             867345315        Book       2019/05/14
3             345456345        Photo      2021/01/23
```

and Table Contacts which is a list of people and their contracts dates (each person can have more than one contract period):

```
Person ID (unique)   Name 
345456345            Paul
867345315            Tom 
879316455            Susan
```

I need to determine the location of each contract.

So I established a relationship as follows:

```
Contracts/Person ID -> Contacts/Person ID
Contacts/Name -> Locals/Name
```

But from here, I am lost. My data visual (table containing Contract/Contract ID, Contacts/Name, Locals/Location) is broken because of the confusion in determining the location of Paul's contracts. The "Fix This" button is telling me that there is a missing relationship between the fields but autodetect isn't finding any relationships (obviously) and I don't know what other relationship I can create manually.

I know the secret is in determining whether the date on the contract falls within the Date Start and Date End of each location belonging to Paul but I don't know how to go about doing that.

Any ideas?

Comment: If the relationship direction is as you are showing, then there's your problem. The direction should be Contacts (`one`) -> Contracts (`many`)

Comment: And creating relationships in text fields is not considered best practice. It would be best if you had person id in the Locals table. It's not what is causing problems, but as a general rule.

Comment: I CANNOT change the incoming data my friend. It is what it is.

Comment: Sure thing, just though it's worth mentioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I took a closer look and I think I know what your problem is. You're trying to show in a visual, which contracts each person had in each location.

When you put Person's name and Location in a table, everything is fine. When you put Person's name and Contract ID everything is fine. The problem starts when you put it all together, as Power BI cannot determine, based on relationships, which contract was signed in which location.

To solve the issue, you would have to create a measure that would (for instance) count these contracts taking dates into account. Something like this:

```
#Contracts in Location = 
var dateFrom = SELECTEDVALUE(Locals[Date Start])
var dateTo = SELECTEDVALUE(Locals[Date End])

return
COUNTROWS(FILTER(Contracts, Contracts[Date] >= dateFrom && Contracts[Date] <= dateTo))
```

If you place this measure in your visual, DAX will be able to figure out appropriate relationships based on row context and measure filters.

**EDIT**

Here's a measure that will also count contracts, when there is no person in the calculation context (by introducing it). I will assume that there is neither gap nor overlap for location dates for a single person.

```
#Contracts in Location =
SUMX (
    Contacts,
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS (
            FILTER (
                Contracts,
                Contracts[Date] >= MIN ( Locals[Date Start] )
                    && Contracts[Date] <= MAX ( Locals[Date End] )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: I'm curious... when I drop the measure into a card, it shows the correct value as long as I select a row in the table. However, if no rows are selected, the card just says blank. How can I make it so the card shows the number of all contracts in all locations instead of being blank?

Comment: That's because the way it's constructed it always expects one location to be in the context. It depends whether you are sure that there are no overlaps in terms of location start/end dates for a single person. Let me update my post in a sec

Comment: There are indeed no overlaps

Comment: So I noticed that there turns out that some employees don't have complete contract histories... meaning that an employee might have made a sale in 2018 but I only have contracts history after 2019. In these cases, the table has a blank in the office name and the count of contracts is ignoring those sales which have a blank office name.

Comment: So what sort of logic would you employ? Where would you like to assign these contracts?

Comment: I would assume that the contract that ended last continues to apply for the sale. I'd only look at the next contract if there is no contract info from before the sale. Meaning if the last contract ended in 2017 but the sale was in 2018, use that contract. If the sale was in 2018 and there is no contract before that date, then use the contract that start in 2020. It should only be blank if there are no contracts at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do it with your tables structure, but it would be better to change a bit your model.

That said, to obtain the following table visual, it's necessary to add also the contract ID set as "Don't summarize". This is needed to stop the table visual to try aggregate the rows, to allow the `ContractLocation` measure to work with the correct filter context, that must contain a single contract and a single contact.

[image: table visual]

[image: Don't summarize]

and use a measure to set the relationship over the dates

```
ContractLocation = 
VAR CurrentContractDate = SELECTEDVALUE( Contracts[Date] )
RETURN
    IF(
        NOT ISBLANK( CurrentContractDate ),
        CALCULATE( 
            SELECTEDVALUE( Locals[Location] ), 
            FILTER( Locals, Locals[Date Start] <= CurrentContractDate && Locals[Date End] >= CurrentContractDate )
        )
    )
```

Edit: adding measure to also match location when there are no matching intervals

This measure uses the last known location. If the contract is before the first know location, then it uses the first known location. To be tested.

```
FuzzyContractLocation = 
IF (
    ISEMPTY ( Locals ) && NOT ISEMPTY(Contracts),
    "Locale unknown",
    VAR CurrentContractDate =
        SELECTEDVALUE ( Contracts[Date] )
    RETURN
        IF (
            NOT ISBLANK ( CurrentContractDate ),
            VAR MinDateStart =
                MIN ( Locals[Date Start] )
            VAR MaxDateStart =
                CALCULATE (
                    MAX ( Locals[Date Start] ),
                    Locals[Date Start] <= CurrentContractDate,
                    REMOVEFILTERS ( Locals[Date End] ),
                    REMOVEFILTERS ( Locals[Location] )
                )
            VAR DateStart =
                IF ( ISBLANK ( MaxDateStart ), MinDateStart, MaxDateStart )
            RETURN
                CALCULATE ( SELECTEDVALUE ( Locals[Location] ), Locals[Date Start] = DateStart )
        )
)
```

This would be better to be done in the data cleansing stage of the ETL, by building a consistent location table.

Comment: But what if the CurrentContractDate doesn't fit inside the filter? For example if CurrentContractDate is 2018-01-01 but the filter only had Locals[Date Start] = 2016/01/01 and Locals[Date End] = 2017/12/31 it returns blank... I would like it to use the date range which is expired last. If there are no expired date ranges, then use the earliest date range that follows CurrentContractDate (ex: 2020/01/01 - 2021/12/31.

Comment: I wrote a measure that should implement the matching with the previously known location. To be tested

Comment: Not quite, it's only returning fields for situations where there are no matching intervals. It seems to be using the next existing interval in all cases rather than only if a previous interval doesn't exist. It also isn't returning any results where an interval does exist.

Comment: You are right. There still were filters to be removed. I also implemented the special case where no location exists for a Contact. Anyway, even if it works it's just a DAX exercise. A good solution requires a change of the model and some data cleansing in the data source to prepare a consistent location table.